# How do i make my Jittery DropDown Menu stable?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im trying to create a Drop-Down menu which appears when a user Hover's above his UserName.

Something that almost all websites have...
It works but when i hover above the Dropdown menu it jitters for a second. Why is this happening and how can i stop it?

Here is my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gec6G/)

Here is my CODE
HTML

```
<a id="dnn_dnnUser_registerLink" title="Visit My Profile" class="UserLink" href="#">Test Account</a>

<ul id="account-dropdown" style="display: none;">
    <li>My Account</li>
    <li>My Orders</li>
    <li>Logout</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$("#dnn_dnnUser_registerLink, #account-dropdown").hover(

function () {
    $("#account-dropdown").slideDown(100);
}, function () {
    $("#account-dropdown").slideUp(100);
});
```

CSS

```
#account-dropdown {
    width:120px;
    display: none;
    background-color:#0A3151;
    opacity:0.8;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:9999;
}
#account-dropdown li {
    list-style:none;
}
```

Comment: That fiddle hurts my eyes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check to see whether the target when mouse out is `#dnn_dnnUser_registerLink` or not, if not then slide up the hidden dropdown:

```
$("#dnn_dnnUser_registerLink, #account-dropdown").hover(function (e) {
    $("#account-dropdown").slideDown(100);
}, function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('#dnn_dnnUser_registerLink')) {
        $("#account-dropdown").slideUp(100);
    }
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gec6G/3/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can add a stop()

```
function () {
    $("#account-dropdown").stop().slideDown(100);
}, function () {
    $("#account-dropdown").stop().slideUp(100);
});
```

This stops any animation currently happening, updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gec6G/4/

Answer (score 1):

I'd put the menu and its options on the same parent div (with some clearfix as needed), and put there the roll out handler.

Answer (score 0):

The event is attached to to both the anchor and the dropdown.

Change  - `$("#dnn_dnnUser_registerLink, #account-dropdown").hover`

To - `$("#dnn_dnnUser_registerLink").hover`